# move data from one table to another with duplicate rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am writing this query to move data from one table to another.

Target table

```
Task
id
assignedtoid
decription
```

Source table

```
 id
 taskid
 comments
```

The query

```
UPDATE
    Task
SET
    Task.[Description] = TMC.Comment
FROM
    Task    
INNER JOIN     
    TaskComment TMC 
ON     
    Task.Id = TMC.TaskId
WHERE
    Task.AssignToId in(some ids)
```

Problem: There are some task that have multiple comment that is not moving with this query?

How can we achieve it, I am using sql server 2005

Comment: Have you made this query yourself ? The syntax is wrong.

Comment: yes the query is made by me, what seems to be the problem....

Comment: down voters atleat there shuould be some comments for downvoting. Also if you can't answer stop downvoting...

Comment: You are not joining the tables correctly. It looks like you could take a break, walk out, and then get back to work. Don't mind the downvotes. Its pretty common in SO.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev, I don't see anything wrong with the query. Curious though what have you seen wrong?

Comment: You'r query is syntactically correct. You have 1:m relationship between these two tables, right? So, in case there are multiple rows in `TaskComment` table, which one should end up written to the `Task` table? Could you give us a sample of source data and the expected result?

Comment: @Rahul - look at the number of times the question was edited. then you'll know.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your query a bit but you are not getting the other comment data cause those new records are not present in your Task table. So, you will have to insert those new records from TaskComment table.

```
UPDATE
    Task
SET
    [Description] = TMC.Comment
FROM
    Task t   
INNER JOIN     
    TaskComment TMC 
ON     
    t.Id = TMC.TaskId
WHERE
    t.AssignToId in (1,2,3)
```

to achieve this in SQL Server 2008 you can use `MERGE` statement but since you are using SQL Server 2005, you can use another alternative (Idea taken from here [mimicking-merge-statement-in-sql](http://sqlserver-tips.blogspot.in/2006/09/mimicking-merge-statement-in-sql.html)) as explained below with a sample.

```
-- Create table1
CREATE TABLE Table1 (Col1 INT, Col2 INT, Col3 VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO Table1 (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT 1, 11, 'First'
UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 12, 'Second'
UNION ALL
SELECT 21, 13, 'Third'
UNION ALL
SELECT 31, 14, 'Fourth'
GO
-- Create table2
CREATE TABLE Table2 (Col1 INT, Col2 INT, Col3 VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO Table2 (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT 1, 21, 'Two-One'
UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 22, 'Two-Two'
UNION ALL
SELECT 21, 23, 'Two-Three'
UNION ALL
SELECT 31, 24, 'Two-Four'
UNION All
SELECT 21, 33, 'Two-Six'
UNION ALL
SELECT 31, 34, 'Two-Nine'
GO

SELECT *
FROM Table1
SELECT *
FROM Table2
GO


declare @updated_ids table(col2 int)
UPDATE Table1
SET Col2 = t2.Col2,
Col3 = t2.Col3
output inserted.col2 into @updated_ids
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col1
WHERE t1.Col1 IN (21, 31)

insert into Table1
select col1, col2, col3 from Table2 
where col2 not in(select col2 from @updated_ids)
go

DROP TABLE Table1
DROP TABLE Table2
```

So in your case, you should do something like

```
declare @updated_ids table(id int)
UPDATE
    Task
SET
    [Description] = TMC.Comment
output inserted.Id into @updated_ids
FROM
    Task t   
INNER JOIN     
    TaskComment TMC 
ON     
    t.Id = TMC.TaskId
WHERE
    t.AssignToId in (1,2,3)

    insert into Task
    select id,
    taskid,
    comments 
    from TaskComment 
    where taskid not in (select id from @updated_ids)
    go
```